# Elm: Pass current time as an effect to Tick Action, after model update

Tags: elm

In `update` I would like to call my `Tick` Action every time `Input` is called.

The scenario is that a user enters a value in a text field, on update the model is updated via `Input` and then `Tick` is called and more stuff is performed on the model.

In 0.16 I could do something like this :

```
Input query ->
  ({ model | query = query }, Effects.tick Tick)

Tick clockTime ->
  -- do something with clockTime
```

I'm not sure how to do this in `0.17`.

I'm not sure if this would be a `subscription` and if it were, how you could go about configuring it to call Input then Action.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effects.tick replacement for elm 0.17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196357/effects-tick-replacement-for-elm-0-17)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality for retrieving the current time as an effect has been moved into a `Task`, in the `Time` module under `Time.now`.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Time#now

You can reproduce your functionality by making the following changes:

1) Make sure there is a `NoOp` message available in your messages. `Time.now` returns a `Task` which we know will never fail, but we still need a failure message to hand to `Task.perform`

```
type Msg
  = Input String
  | Tick Time
  | NoOp
```

2) Replace `Effects.tick Tick` with `Time.now` and `Task.perform`

```
Input query ->
  ( { model | query = query }
  , Time.now |> Task.perform (\_ -> NoOp) Tick
  )
```

If you don't like the `NoOp` message, there are other ways around it, such as using `Debug.crash` or `performFailproof` from `Task.Extra` (found here: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-task-extra/2.0.0/Task-Extra#performFailproof)

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, so I apologise if my question wasn't clear. Thank you.